# $A[t/x]$ in formal logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have been trying to understand some first-order logic, but it's basically seeming like randomly-generated nonsense.

$ A \equiv ( \exists y \enspace \lnot Q(x,y)\lor \forall z Q(x,z))$ where $t\equiv c,$

so $A[t/x] \equiv  ( \exists y \enspace \lnot Q(c,y)\lor \forall z Q(c,z)).$

$ A \equiv ( \exists y \enspace \lnot Q(x,y)\lor \forall z Q(x,z))$ where $t\equiv y,$

so $A[t/x] \equiv  ( \exists y \enspace \lnot Q(x,y)\lor \forall z Q(y,z)).$

Why did we arbitrarily choose to substitute in for t in some parts of the formulae but not in others?

Comment: Because the term $y$ is not "free for" the first occurrence of the variable $x$ in the wff $A$, because that occurrence of $x$ is within the scope of a $y$ quantifier, but it is free for the second occurrence of $x$ -- whereas the term $c$ (since it has no variables) is free for both occurrences of $x$ in $A$. Your logic text should have something about this -- it's technical but necessary so that (roughly) the new wff says the same thing about $t$ that the original said about $x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definition of "substitutable" in Mathematical Logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648628/definition-of-substitutable-in-mathematical-logic)

Comment: Substitution is the process of putting a "name" in the empty place of a statement that is represented with a (free) variable. If we have the "pseudo-statement" "x is a Philosopher", we replace the name "Socrates" in the empty place to get the complete statement: "Socrates is a Philosopher".

Comment: A quantified variable does not represent an empty place: the statement "Everyone is a Philosopher" has no empty places. Thus, to replace the x of "for every x (x is a Philosopher)" with the name Socrates leave the statement unaffected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > $ A \equiv ( \exists y \enspace \lnot Q(x,y)\lor \forall z Q(x,z))$ where $t\equiv c,$
   >  so $A[t/x] \equiv  ( \exists y
   >     \enspace \lnot Q(c,y)\lor \forall z Q(c,z)).$
   >
   > $ A \equiv ( \exists y \enspace \lnot Q(x,y)\lor \forall z Q(x,z))$ where $t\equiv y,$
   >  so $A[t/x] \equiv  ( \exists y
   > \enspace \lnot Q(x,y)\lor \forall z Q(y,z)).$
   >
   > Why did we arbitrarily choose to sub in for t in some parts but not
   > others?

   Now, $A[t/x]$
   [typically](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4217579/21813) denotes
   the result of replacing all free occurrences of the variable $x$ in
   formula $A$ with term $t.$ As such, the third occurrence of $x$ in
   the above exerise would technically have been changed from $$\exists y
   \enspace \lnot Q(x,y)$$ to $$\exists y \enspace \lnot Q(y,y),$$ even
   if it turns out that $t$ (here $y$) is **not freely substitutable**
   for $x$ in $A.$

   Since the author declined to make the third substitution, they must
   be defining $A[t/x]$ as the result of replacing every free
   occurrence of the variable $x$ in formula $A$ with term $t$ *in
   which such a replacement results in no variable in $t$ becoming
   bound*.
2. If the goal is to get rid of *every* occurrence of $x$ without
   causing any trouble, we can write:

   $$ A \equiv ( \exists y \enspace \lnot Q(x,y)\lor \forall z
   Q(x,z))\\A[y/x] \equiv  ( \exists z \enspace \lnot Q(y,z)\lor
   \forall z Q(y,z)).$$